# Some good books on application of Gauss-Bonnet-Chern Theorem in general relativity

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I am currently doing an undergraduate project about Gauss-Bonnet-Chern Theorem. Is there any particular book suggestions regarding the application of the theorem in the theory of general relativity?

Edit: I should ask more specifically. Is there any good reference on the application of Gauss-Bonnet-Chern Theorem for four-dimensional manifold on general relativity?

Comment: I suggest you " Riemannian Geometry ". From Frank Morgan.  This book is 103 pages. I think it's been written very fluently. It talks about curves and surfaces in $R^3$ and $R^n$ and then it moves to Riemannian Geometry. And in a separate chapter, it talks about Gauss-Bonnet Theorem. It has a chapter about General Relativity. Probably, its Physic section is not enough for you but its mathematics section gives a good view.

Comment: Sorry but the text that I need is the implication of Gauss Bonnet Chern Theorem in physics .

Comment: I see. I don't know Physics. But Riemannian Geometry provides a mathematical framework that makes calculation possible for General Relativity. Seemingly, to know the interaction between these two can be helpful.

Comment: A quick web search produced [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern–Gauss–Bonnet_theorem#Applications), although that's probably not specific enough.

Comment: @LeeMosher, yes I get this also when I am searching for the application. But I need some text which is more specific. I should say that I need some references on application of Gauss-Bonnet Theorem for four-dimensional manifold in physics.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you will have entire books devoted to the subject, as you hoped for.

Here are however two papers in which some version of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem (unfortunately not the 4 dimensional version) makes interesting appearances.

1. In [a work of Galloway and Schoen](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0509107), they studied the question of "what can be the topology of a black hole" extending on previous works of Hawking. Through analytic methods they conclude that the surface of the black hole must be a manifold that supports a metric of positive scalar curvature, which in the case of 4 dimensional spacetimes (where the black hole surface is two dimensional) tells you that the surface have to be spherical.
2. In a [never published note of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6279v2), I asked the question of whether there is an analogue to the positive mass theorem when looking only at spacetimes with 2 spatial and 1 time dimensions. (This was not entirely idle in view of holography and AdS-CFT correspondences.) In any case, the result follows from an application of the classical Gauss-Bonnet theorem.